# Derivate of superior order for compound function

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is:

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, whith $n$ derivates. If exist $a\in \mathbb{R}$ with $f'(a)=\cdots =f^{(n)}(a)=0$ then $(g\circ f)^{(i)}=0$ for $i=1,...,n$

I think in use inducction for find a general expresion of $(g\circ f)^{(i)}$ and show explicit that all members are multiplicated by any derivate of $f$ but is hard get a general expresion. 
I foun in a book the next exercise:

If $f,g$ are functions in the same conditions then for any naturals $n_1,...,n_k$ with $n=n_1+\cdots+n_k$ exist an integer number $\alpha=\alpha(n_1,...,n_k)$

$$(g\circ f)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha(n_1,...,n_k)\cdot (g^{(k)}\circ f)\cdot f^{(n_1)}\cdot f^{(n_2)}\cdots f^{(n_k)}$$

where for each $k=1,...,n$ is valid $n=n_1+\cdots+n_k$

This theorem helps to show the dependence of the drivates of $f$ but I can't do this exercise.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Your statement doesn't look quite right; you'll have to sum over partitions of $n$ rather than specifying $n_{1}, \dots, n_{k}$ in advance. But that aside, the case $n = 1$ follows from the chain rule; proceed by induction on $n$. It will probably help to work out the first few cases explicitly. :)